# Rendering site directly on tomcat whilst serving static files from the webserver above

Tags: tomcat8

I are trying to decouple our dependency between the tomcat server and static resources war file as each time a file is changed we have to redeploy it. Currently we deploy the static resources on tomcat and also on the nginx webserver that sits in front of it. All public requests for static files are proxied to the local disk on the webserver however to render the page directl on the tomcat server we also need to deploy these static files on the tomcat server purely for the operator to troubleshoot.
We want to deploy the static files to least amount of locations without duplicating the same on web tier and the tomcat tier whilst retaining all functionality.
Any advise how to decouple this ? We are hosted in AWS

Comment: Is Apache-Tomcat and Nginx on the same server?

Comment: No nginx sits before the tomcat server

Traffic flow: proxy -> nginx -> tomcat